Converting pipe-separated file with fields containing quotation marks to GeoJSON
I have this pipe separated file, input.psv:
COL0|GEOM
abc|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0, 1]}
dXe|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2, 3]}
fgh|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4, 5]}

Using this answer, I can convert it to output.geojson:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.geojson input.psv -nln main -oo SEPARATOR=PIPE -oo GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES='GEOM'

Resulting in this output.geojson:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "main",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "abc", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 1 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 1.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "dXe", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 3 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.0, 3.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "fgh", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4, 5 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.0, 5.0 ] } }
]
}

However, to my slight surprise, X cannot be any non-pipe character (2nd character of the 2nd non-header row) for this transformation to work. For example, I cannot replace X with a ". If input.psv is:
COL0|GEOM
abc|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0, 1]}
d"e|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2, 3]}
fgh|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4, 5]}

Then using the above ogr2ogr command:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.geojson input.psv -nln main -oo SEPARATOR=PIPE -oo GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES='GEOM'

results in this output.geojson:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "main",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "abc", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 1 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 1.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "d\"e", "GEOM": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[2, 3]}\nfgh" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.0, 3.0 ] } }
]
}

This file has only 2 features (count or ogrinfo output.geojson main -so -json | jq '.layers[].featureCount'), while input.psv had 3, which is a problem. I expected output.geojson to be something like:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "main",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "abc", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 1 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 1.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "d\"e", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 3 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.0, 3.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "fgh", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4, 5 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.0, 5.0 ] } }
]
}

How can I use ogr2ogr to convert a pipe-separated file with fields containing quotation marks to GeoJSON?
ogr2ogr --version returns: GDAL 3.8.5, released 2024/04/02.

From the CSV driver doc : "Complex attribute values (such as those containing commas, quotes or newlines) may be placed in double quotes. Any occurrences of double quotes within the quoted string should be doubled up to "escape" them."

You input CSV is a wrong CSV. If you correct it, you will have no problem

By "wrong", do you mean it does not conform to the GDAL driver specification the first comment mentions, or do you have some other basis to call it "wrong"? Pandas can read it perfectly. Calling it "wrong" because it doesn't conform to the expectation of one particular driver of a particular software seems unjustified to me.

Your use case is a bit complicated because double quotation marks in CSV have a special meaning for GDAL as marking strings in between them. GDAL tries to handle double quotes as normal characters if they are escaped with another double quatation mark, and it knows that JSON contains double quotes by nature https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/vector/csv.html.

Complex attribute values (such as those containing commas, quotes or
newlines) may be placed in double quotes. Any occurrences of double
quotes within the quoted string should be doubled up to "escape" them.

Notice that according to the documentation your JSON field actually should not work, even I can confirm that it works with the test data:

Otherwise, if one or several columns contain a geometry definition
encoded as WKT, WKB (encoded in hexadecimal) or GeoJSON (in which case
the GeoJSON content must be formatted to follow CSV rules, that is to
say it must be surrounded by double-quotes, and double-quotes inside
the string must be repeated for proper escaping),

I had a try by editing your input data in two places:

Enclose the first string fields between double quotes on all rows
Escape the internal " with another "

    COL0|GEOM
    "abc"|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0, 1]}
    "d""e"|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2, 3]}
    "fgh"|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4, 5]}


With this input I got output
    {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "main",
    "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "abc", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0, 1 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 1.0 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "d\"e", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 3 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.0, 3.0 ] } },
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "COL0": "fgh", "GEOM": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4, 5 ] } }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.0, 5.0 ] } }
    ]
    }

